# Wordpress single.php different layouts projects / posts

Tags: posts, page-template, single

i'm new in Wordpress and I'm currently building my personal website where my works will be published and have a blog too. For the portfolio layout I've looked up this tutorial:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/create-a-multi-layout-portfolio-with-wordpress/

It gives me what I want, more or less. The point is that when I enter on a specific project, the look of it changes a little bit. The file single.php is working right? But doesn't this means that the blog posts will have the exactly the same layout than the project details? I mean, if I edit that file I'm doing it for both blog posts and project details right?

How can I make it to look different?

Best Regards,
Tiago Castro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the [Custom Post Template plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-template/) and create different templates for your project pages. This works like [page templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates).

You may also consider a [custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) for your projects to use different taxonomies, meta data and templates.

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes if you edit single.php thats impact will be global across the site, to over come from this WordPress provides you elegant way called layout heirarchy
for your post type portfolio you can use different single.php.
Dont edit single create one more file called single-postytype.php for portfolio type it will be single-portfolio.php so that it loads only for portfolio post type, if you wanna have specific layout for blog post then it will be single-post.php
Have a look at this hierarchy you may get idea
http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png